# Can I install/use Python Log Indenter with Revit Python Shell?

Tags: pip, ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I would like to install Python Log Indenter ([Document Page](https://python-log-indenter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ) for use with RevitPytonShell (IronPython version). The docs for Python Log Indenter indicate that PIP be used for installation but I am not sure if that is possible with Revit Python Shell.

Can someone tell me if this is possible? And how to go about it?

Sincerely;
Michelle